# What is the mechanism/process whereby individuals are reviewed and considered for exclusion from the UK by declaration of the secretary of state?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, immigration

This mechanism has been used to exclude individuals such as Edward Snowden, Daryush Valizadeh, and Julian Assange on grounds of being unconducive to the public good. Thankfully this criteria is fairly decently defined by a published list of behaviours in 2005. However, is there a team that reviews public intellectual or political figures and refers them to the home secretary for review and consideration for such exclusion orders? What is the system that triggers one for consideration for such an order?

Answer (score 1):

### [Exclusion on conducive grounds](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1036427/Exclusion_from_the_UK.pdf)

Which covers a wide range of reasons including:

- National security
- Criminality
- International crimes
- Extremism
- Corruption
- Unacceptable behaviour
- Sham marriage

As to what triggers consideration, we have:

> **Official-sensitive: start of section**
>
> The information in this section has been removed as it is restricted for internal Home Office use.
>
> The information in this section has been removed as it is restricted for internal Home Office use.
>
> The information in this section has been removed as it is restricted for internal Home Office use.
>
> **Official-sensitive: end of section**

However, there are certain obvious things that could trigger it and they all involve drawing the attention of the government in some way:

- Applying for a visa
- Attempting to enter the country
- Being placed on an Interpol watch list
- Being arrested or convicted in the UK
- Coming to the attention of the security services
- Media reporting

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139343/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-what-is-the-mechanism-process-whereby-individuals).

Comment: Relevant: https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/42/schedule/1/part/I/chapter/13